# Prestashop - Main Categories on Every Template

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, smarty3

I'm using Prestashop for an eCommerce site.  In the 'product.tpl' I put the following code, which I (eventually) found on a website, and it worked perfectly for my needs.

```
{assign var='category' value=Product::getProductCategoriesFull($product->id, $cookie->id_lang)}

{foreach from=$categories key='categoryId' item='category' name='category'}
    <a href="#">{$category['name']}</a>
 {/foreach}
```

This puts the eleven main categories on the product page for me.  Works great.
Now I need to put those same categories on the page that actually lists categories and subcategories, which I'm using 'category.tpl' for.  That code doesn't work for that template, just no content is loaded at all.

The main categories part is actually supposed to be seen from every page on the website, as part of the header really.  But I'm finding Prestashop to be problematic with includes, which would be the norm with PHP.

I'm trying to not use all the 'overrides' that I keep finding.  It's far too much code that I don't understand.  Can the code I have be slightly modified to work in the category template file (and any other template file on the website)?

Comment: By the way, I know that {'$category->name}' displays the name of the current category.  I do use that, but I need to display the names of the other categories too, for the main menu type part of the site.

Answer (score 0):

You code snippet is either wrong, or you typed it incorrectly:

```
{assign var='category'
```

Creates a variable `$category`. However, it is immediatelly overwritten by 
`from=$categories item='category'` -> looks creates it's own `$category`.

I think you meant `{assign var='categories'`. Anyway, the code may still be working because `$categories` variables is already avaiable in product page (every product has some categories).

Also, you first statement grabs categories for the specified product `$product->id`. Again, `$product` is avaiable in the product page only (logical).

If you want to grab all categories independently of the page, try using:

```
{assign var='all_categories' value=Category::getCategories(Context::getContext()->language->id)}
<pre>{$all_categories|@print_r}</pre>
```

Comment: Your code gives me lots of technical information, but I'm struggling. Here is some of it, and I need to make a simple loop to put categories on the page.
`[2] => Array
(
[12] => Array
(
[infos] => Array
(
[id_category] => 12
[id_parent] => 2
[id_shop_default] => 1
[level_depth] => 2
[nleft] => 3
[nright] => 10
[active] => 1
[date_add] => 2015-03-16 22:34:15
[date_upd] => 2015-03-16 22:34:15
[position] => 1
[is_root_category] => 0
[id_shop] => 1
[id_lang] => 1
[name] => Acer
[description] => 
The Acer plants

[link_rewrite] => acer
[meta_title] => 
[meta_keywords] => 
[meta_description] => 
)`

Comment: I'm sorry about the formatting.  I tried to do it as a list, but it came out that way.  The return key doesn't seem to add a new line in this text box either.  I'm very new to this site.  My apologies.

Comment: Still trying to put little bit of code together. Help with this?  `{foreach from=Category::getCategories(Context::getContext()->language->id) item=cat} <li>{$cat[1].name}</li> {/foreach}`Where that 1 is, would ideally be an index of some kind, to work through the main menu.